# Retrieving Advanced Custom Field within Shortcode Function

Tags: custom-field, shortcode

I'm trying to do something that seems like it should be (and probably is) simple: display the result of Advanced Custom Fields `get_field()` call within the return of a shortcode function.

Within a theme template:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'produce',
    'orderby'               => 'title',
    'order'                 => 'ASC'
  ));


  foreach( $posts as $post ):

    setup_postdata( $post );

    the_title(); 
    print_r(get_field('produce_image'));
```

As desired, `the_title();` displays the title for each custom post item and `get_field('produce_image')` contains the image array for the item.

However within the shortcode, although the `WP_Post Object`s contained in `$posts` are identical, `the_title();` returns the title of the page from which the shortcode is called, and `get_field('produce_image')` doesn't seem to return anything - not even an empty array.

Getting a true return from `function_exists('get_field')`.

The entire shortcode is:

```
<?php

function field_to_fork_produce_display( $atts ) {

  $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'title' => 'Produce'
  ), $atts );

  $title = $atts['title']; 

  /*
  $plugins_dir = plugin_dir_path( __file__ );
  $plugins_dir = str_replace("/field-to-fork/lib/", "", $plugins_dir);
  include_once($plugins_dir.'/advanced-custom-fields/acf.php'); 
  */    

  $result = '<div class="col"><h2 class="text-center"><?=$title?></h2>';

  $posts = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'           => 'produce',
    'orderby'                 => 'title',
    'order'                   => 'ASC'
  ));

  mz_pr($posts);

  if( $posts ): 
?>

<?php

    foreach( $posts as $post ):

      setup_postdata( $post );
      mz_pr(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'produce', true));

?>
<?php 

      if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it. 

        $result .=  '<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">';
        the_post_thumbnail( 'thumb', array( 'class' => "img-responsive img-center"));

      }       

      $result   .=      '</a>';
      $result   .=      '<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">' . the_title() . '</a></h4>';
      $result   .=      '<p>' . the_excerpt() . '</p>';

      if ( ! function_exists( 'get_field' ) ) {
        die('not there');
      }

      mz_pr(function_exists('get_field'));
      mz_pr(get_field('produce_image')); 
      echo get_field('produce_image');
      mz_pr("nothing to see here"); 

      $produce_thumbnail = get_field('produce_image', false, false)['sizes']['thumbnail'];
      $result   .= '<img src="<?=$produce_thumbnail?>" class="img-responsive field_to_fork_thumb <?php the_title(); ?>">';
      $result   .=      '</a>';

    endforeach; 

    wp_reset_postdata(); 

  endif; 

  $result   .= '</div><!-- end span 6-->';

  return $result;
} 

?>
```

Comment: you have to explicitly pass post ID as the 2nd argument.

Comment: `get_field('produce_image', $post->ID)`! Thank you. Will self-answer if you or someone else doesn't first. `get_the_title($post->ID)` and `get_the_excerpt()` also return the desired values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You have to explicitly pass post ID as the 2nd argument." – Milo

In the Advanced Custom Fields plugin file, `plugins/advanced-custom-fields/core/api.php`, `get_fields` has a default `$post_id` of false, and calls on `get_field_objects`, which seems to run specific calls to `$wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare`, depending on what `$post_id` contains (`is_numeric?`, `strpos('user_')`), so I guess depending on the environment of the loop you're calling it from it will return different results, unless `$post->ID` is specified.

So as specified by @Milo above:

```
get_field('produce_image', $post->ID)
```

Will get us the image object.

I think `get_the_title($post->ID)` is native Wordpress and probably works similarly.

Running `get_the_excerpt($post->ID)` returns a warning:

`get_the_excerpt was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.3 with no alternative available.`, but just running `get_the_excerpt()` is returning the post excerpt as desired.